# Search a secure way to connect to my remote server

Tags: java, android, linux, csv, server

I actually realise a project on Android Studio. To get the data, I put the URL path of my csv file with the format : **ftp://login:password@IP/path_File**.
   But I guess this is not secure. How can I secure that ? I did some research. Some people say to put the password in configuration file but I don't see what this changes. It's important because with these informations, people can directly read the csv file and I don't want that.
   Please can you guide me to secure that ? Thanks for your help.
   Have a nice day.

Comment: Do you mean that the Csv file can be accessed on the phone or can be read on your versioning software ( Git, bitbucket,... )?

Comment: My Csv file is in a Server. Actually, I don't use a versioning server but yes if I put my code on Git, I guess that people can access to the Csv file (with the login and password).

Comment: Ah the file itself is on the server, I had the idea that your credentials where stored in there. My mistake! You can put your URL in a text file of some sort and exclude it from your project. This way your URL is hidden and the file is not visible.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i must to put link to this file which contains the Url. If not my application will not find the Url and this problem is still here ? What do you mean about exclude? Put him on the server ?

Comment: You need the link with the plain password/username to connect to your FTP server. But you don't want it visible for all to see. So from what I read in your previous answer is that you are not using Git. You can however like you mentioned before create a property file containing the link. Should you want to use Git or something else then you need to make sure that this file does not end on Git by excluding it ( this means adding this file to the .gitignore file ). https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Or if you want to try something else then please have a look at: https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/

Comment: Ok thanks, i will see that !

Comment: For example, I can put the URL in the String.xml file and put my project in Git without the file String.xml (with gitignore) ?

Comment: Yes you can do that.